# passing UTF-8 through a python script from a subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

In a python3 script, I setup UTF-8 output with:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

I then launch a subprocess with subprocess.Popen, and scan the results, trying to print a subset. The output is \x-escaped when it contains interesting characters. This is not what I want, I just want the UTF-8. The unwanted output is at the bottom.

```
process = subprocess.Popen([MVN, "-Ptrain-model"],
            cwd=JPN_MODELS_DIR, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print_interesting_info(process.stdout)

def print_interesting_info(out):
   TRAINING_FLAG = False

    for buffer_line in out:
       #line = str(buffer_line, "utf8").strip()
       line = str(buffer_line).strip()
       if ("ERROR" in line):
            print(line)
```

Unwanted output:

```
b'[ERROR] next segment length 109 > LONGEST_WORD input \xef\xbc\xa1\xef\xbc\x8e\xef\xbc\xa1\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x86\xef\xbd\x8f\xef\xbd\x8c\xef\xbd\x84\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbc\x8c\xef\xbc\xa4\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbc\xab\xef\xbd\x8f\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x8f\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbc\x8c\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x96\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x8b\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbc\xb0\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x8f\xef\xbd\x90\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x87\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x84\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x8d\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x8c\xef\xbd\x84\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x84\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x8f\xef\xbd\x8d\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x83\xef\xbd\x88\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x88\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x84\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x83\xef\xbd\x88\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbc\xa1\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x8f\xef\xbd\x8b\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x88\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x8d\xef\xbc\xab\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x8d\xef\xbd\x90\xef\xbd\x86\xef\xbd\x87\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x87\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x8e\xef\xbd\x84\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x83\xef\xbd\x88\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x8c\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x83\xef\xbd\x88\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbc\xab\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x89\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x92\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbd\x95\xef\xbd\x8d\xef\xbc\x8c\xef\xbc\xa2\xef\xbd\x95\xef\xbd\x84\xef\xbd\x81\xef\xbd\x90\xef\xbd\x85\xef\xbd\x93\xef\xbd\x94\xef\xbc\x8c\xef\xbc\x91\xef\xbc\x99\xef\xbc\x94\xef\xbc\x93\xef\xbc\x91\xef\xbc\x99\xef\xbc\x94\xef\xbc\x93\xef\xbc\x91\xef\xbc\x99\xef\xbc\x94\xef\xbc\x93\xef\xbc\x91\xef\xbc\x99\xef\xbc\x94\xef\xbc\x93\xe5\x8f\x82\xe7\x85\xa7\xe3\x80\x82\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process.stdout` is an `io.BufferedReader`. It reads `bytes`, and `bytes.__str__` is basically a `repr` of the byte string. You can wrap it in an `io.TextIOWrapper`:

```
import io

print_interesting_info(out):
    TRAINING_FLAG = False

    out = io.TextIOWrapper(out, 'utf-8')
    for line in out:
        line = line.strip()
        if "ERROR" in line:
            print(line)
```